# Finding a convex upper-bound and lower bound on the expectation of $\ln(1+x)$ when $x\sim \text{Gamma}(k,\theta)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, gamma-distribution

I need to evaluate the expectation of $\ln(1+x)$ when $x\sim \text{Gamma}(k,\theta)$. I know that this integral

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \ln(1+x) \right] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1+x) \frac{x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)}dx$$

has no closed form solution unfortunately and only when $x\gg1$, we can approximate it with $\mathbb{E}\left[ \ln(1+x) \right] \approx \mathbb{E}\left[ \ln(x) \right] = \gamma(k) + \ln(\theta)$. However none of these results are convex. I wanted to know if there is any studies on finding convex upper or lower bounds for this integral $\mathbb{E}\left[ \ln(1+x) \right]$?!

Any hints and/or references would be appreciated.

===============================Edit==============================

The original problem is like this

$$\begin{align}
&\underset{a_i}{\max} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}_{x_i}\left[ \ln(1+\frac{a_i}{a_0}x_i) \right]\\
& \text{s.t.} \quad \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i \le A \\
& \forall i:  \frac{a_i}{a_0} \le m_i
\end{align}$$

Where $A,m_i$ are given constants. $x_i\sim \text{Gamma}(k_i,\theta_i)$.

Comment: (Your integrand lacks a factor of $\exp(-x).$)  What specifically are "these results" to which you refer and in what sense do you mean "convex"? Please bear in mind that you are asking for bounds that must be functions of *both* $k$ and $\theta$ simultaneously.  So maybe you want the bounds to be convex functions of $(k,\theta)$? Do they have to be convex for all $k\gt 0$ or just for sufficiently large $k$? Why not just take any pair of bounds and replace them with their upper convex hulls?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I corrected the equations. The final result of the integral is a function of $k,\theta$, if it is possible, convex with respect to both $k,\theta$ but such dreams are most likely, unlikely, a result that is convex in terms of $\theta$ is preferable. My ultimate goal is to optimize this integral with respect to some parameters and since the original form of integral was $\mathbb{E}[\ln(1+ax)]$ and $a$ is my target parameter, it will be absorbed into $\theta$. Thank you for this comment, it shed some light on the objective here. Also the range of $a$ is small to moderate

Comment: For large value of $a$ I use the Digamma approximation and one dimensional search, because it is a well known result. Here by large $a$ I mean $10^3\sim 10^4$, moderate values are $10\sim 100$ and small values are $0.1\sim 10$. $a$ represents some field strength parameter. Is my perception of the problem correct?

Comment: It would be nice to see a clear formulation of the original optimization problem.  It might be more productive--and perhaps even easier--than pursuing this approximation question.

Comment: Jensen gives you an upper bound: $\mathbb{E}[\ln(1+X)]\leq\ln(1+k\theta)$.

Comment: Re the original problem: there must be some typographical error, because (otherwise) you may choose $a_0$ arbitrarily small (yet positive) and set all other $a_i=(A-a_0)/n,$ making your objective function equal to $n$ times the expectation of $\log(1 + a_1x_1/a_0)\gt\log(a_1)-\log(a_0)+\log(x_1),$ which you can make arbitrarily large.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry, forgot to mention the slope constraints, they are added now.

Comment: I like the optimization question, but I would delete the original question about convex bounds (since even a good answer to the original question might not help you optimize).

Comment: @Matt F. I was thinking about a convex approximation to get an upper or lower bound on solution. I would appreciate other ideas to approach this beast. Thank you!